$SU(2)$ as global and local symmetry
I am trying to understand the (historical) motivation for studying $SU(2)$ Yang-Mills as generalization of electro-magnetism, which is an abelian gauge theory with local $U(1)$ symmetry. I am wondering if the discovery of spin as a global symmetry plays a role. Let me explain what I mean by it being a "global symmetry" (I hope I am not misusing physics jargon).
Spin as a global symmetry of quantum mechanics
In my understanding, the discovery of spin (through Stern-Gerlach experiment), led one to consider two-component spinors $\psi \in \mathbb{C}^2$ for which there exist no representation of $SO(3)$ (and more generally of the proper orthochronous Lorentz group). This presents a serious issue, which is solved through the fact that wave functions and thus the representation of an element $R \in SO(3)$ is only determined up to a sign. One thus does not need a representation of $SO(3)$, but only a 2-valued representation, which is exactly a representation of it's double cover $Spin(3)=SU(2)$ (or $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$) in the case of the full proper orthochronous Lorentz group). The same holds true for four-component spinors arising from the Dirac equation: There are only representations of the double covers, which is fine, since the wave functions are also only determined up to a sign.
Question
Is the discovery of Spin in physics, which is a lift of the global symmetry group of $SO(3)$ to $SU(2)$ related to the interest in $SU(2)$ as a local symmetry in Yang-Mills theory?
My thought
Maybe, since $SU(2)$ presents the rotational part of the full Lorentz symmetry, one can understand $SU(2)$ as part of the global symmetry as well as part of some internal rotation, ie, spin.

Hint: Lookup spacetime symmetries vs. internal symmetries and the Coleman–Mandula theorem.

Thanks for your comment. From a quick reading, my understanding of the theorem is that global and local symmetries "cannot be mixed" (ie the total symmetry group, must be a direct product of the global and local symmetries). This is interesting, but does not really answer my question. Thinking in terms of bundles this possibility did not even occur to me. My question is, why was SU(2) an interesting candidate for a local symmetry and is this related to spin?

You are irredeemably misguided. Spin hardly figures into this, beyond formal inspiration for isospin, group-theoretically similar. You should be asking a straight question on HSM where this belongs. Y-M gauged the SU(2) of global isospin, an internal symmetry.

I have to admit that I don't know what isospin is. Judging by your comment, isospin is completely unrelated to spin?


My question is, why was SU(2) an interesting candidate for a local symmetry and is this related to spin?

SU(2) was a very important candidate in the early 1950s when the gauging was successfully carried out by Yang & Mills, since it is the symmetry group of isospin underlying low-energy strong interactions, nuclear binding, light hadrons and quarks.
The very same group describes spin, linked to the Lorentz group, a physically completely disparate concept, so the math is the same, but the physics is different, here completely irrelevant: a red herring.
Mathematical analogy is not to be sneered at, however. The global flavor group of SU(2), isospin, above, was extended to flavor SU(3) triumphantly in the next decade; and thence, just as SU(2), it was trivial to gauge technically, but bootlessly for a brief while.
Neither gauge theory was physically useful at the time; but soon, in the late 1960s, they were retrofitted, twice!,  to completely different physical symmetries, so that, today, they underlie all of the Standard Model. Particle physics is essentially their study!
The SU(2) gauge theory, suitably modified, applied to weak isospin, ended up describing the weak interactions successfully; while the SU(3) one was applied to QCD, the triumphant theory of subhadron strong interactions.
